# css: start to fill repeat-y from bottom

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to start the background repeat-y from the bottom?

I need to highlight stars using overlap div
Here what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/ghKb2/43/

or, code here:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
.ratings {
font-size:11px;
line-height:1.25;
margin:2px 0 0;
}

.rating-box {
width:14px;
height:65px;
font-size:0;
line-height:0;
background:url("https://incinqueterre.com/images/bkg_rating_vertical.gif") 0 0 repeat-y;
text-indent:-999em;
overflow:hidden;
}

.rating-box .rating {
height:65px;
background:url("https://incinqueterre.com/images/bkg_rating_vertical.gif") 100% 0 repeat-y;
}

.ratings .rating-box {
margin-right:7px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="ratings">
<div class="rating-box">
<div class="rating" style="height:85%" title="4.3/5"></div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just changing the line in side `.rating` from:

```
background:url("https://incinqueterre.com/images/bkg_rating_vertical.gif") 100% 0 repeat-y;
```

To:

```
background:url("https://incinqueterre.com/images/bkg_rating_vertical.gif") 100% 100% repeat-y;
```

Or what I think is more readable (better shows the intent):

```
background:url("https://incinqueterre.com/images/bkg_rating_vertical.gif") right bottom repeat-y;
```

Works, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ghKb2/45/